Size of starting guest in VirtualBox
Is there a way how to increse inicial screen size of starting guest in VirtualBox?

VM is created
First start of VM by booting from ISO
Dialog appears but only upper part, the rest is out of the frame (screen)

Scale factor does not help - it just zooms the whole frame (screen) with its content

Virtualbox doesnt initialize to a certain resolution, the guest OS does. You'll have to look into a way to change the resolution of the ISO installer you are booting from.
